# SpagoBI Socket connection error at cockpit widget creation

Tags: java, tomcat7, spagobi

I have installed SpagoBI 5.1 with java version as 1.8.0_121.
I tried to create a new cockpit and add new widget. But getting following error:

> Impossible to load dataset [XXXXXX] due to the following service
>   errors:socket creation error;

Below is stacktrace from `catalina.out`:

```
it.eng.spagobi.rest.interceptors.RestExceptionMapper.toResponseFromGenericException: Catched service error:it.eng.spagobi.utilities.exceptions.SpagoBIServiceException: An unexpected error occured while executing service
        at it.eng.spagobi.api.DataSetResource.getDataStore(DataSetResource.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An unexpected error occured while executing method
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.DatasetManagementAPI.getDataStore(DatasetManagementAPI.java:401)
        at it.eng.spagobi.api.DataSetResource.getDataStore(DataSetResource.java:224)
        ... 34 more Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.CacheException: An unexpected error occured while initializing cache
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.SpagoBICacheManager.initializeCache(SpagoBICacheManager.java:76)
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.SpagoBICacheManager.getCache(SpagoBICacheManager.java:59)
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.DatasetManagementAPI.getDataStore(DatasetManagementAPI.java:377)
        ... 35 more it.eng.spagobi.rest.interceptors.RestExceptionMapper.toResponseFromGenericException: Catched service error: it.eng.spagobi.utilities.exceptions.SpagoBIServiceException: An unexpected error occured while executing service
        at it.eng.spagobi.api.DataSetResource.getDataStore(DataSetResource.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An unexpected error occured while executing method
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.DatasetManagementAPI.getDataStore(DatasetManagementAPI.java:401)
        at it.eng.spagobi.api.DataSetResource.getDataStore(DataSetResource.java:224)
        ... 34 more Caused by: it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.CacheException: An unexpected error occured while initializing cache
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.SpagoBICacheManager.initializeCache(SpagoBICacheManager.java:76)
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.cache.SpagoBICacheManager.getCache(SpagoBICacheManager.java:59)
        at it.eng.spagobi.tools.dataset.DatasetManagementAPI.getDataStore(DatasetManagementAPI.java:377)
        ... 35 more
```

I am running SpagoBI on Ubuntu 16.04(Linux) server. Following is output I am getting in terminal when SpagoBIStartup.sh is executed:

```
[Server@5451c3a8]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@5451c3a8]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@5451c3a8]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@5451c3a8]: Loaded properties from [/var/www/html/[DIR_SPAGO]/database/server.properties]
[Server@5451c3a8]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@5451c3a8]: Server socket opened successfully in 7 ms.
[Server@5451c3a8]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @5451c3a8,5,main]]: Database [index=0db=file:./foodmart, alias=foodmart] did not open: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Out of Memory
[Server@5451c3a8]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @5451c3a8,5,main]]: run()/openDatabases(): 
[Server@5451c3a8]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@5451c3a8]: Shutdown sequence completed in 1 ms.
[Server@5451c3a8]: 2017-01-27 07:33:12.852 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() is called next
```

Here is the screenshot: 
[image: Spago Socket creation error]
Any help is welcome !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was memory issue.. Connection to Foodmart database was not getting opened.. We upgraded our server to server with bigger memory.. and this issue got resolved..